# WordPress opens .docx instead of downloading

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with one of my WordPress websites and I don't know why it's happening.
If I click on the `.pdf` link, it opens in the browser (not much of a problem). If i click on the .doc link, the browser allows me to download it (good).

If i click on the `.docx`, it opens the file itself in a new tab and shows symbols instead of allowing me to download it.

I tried it on different browsers and the behavior is the same.
Both websites are running on `openlitespeed` with `php 7.4`.

Rewrite rules on both websites are as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, on one website everything is fine - if I click on the link with `.docx` it allows me to download it, and on the other it opens it in the browser.
Don't know if it has something to do with it, but the website that doesn't have any issues is running on locally installed `vm` with `Almalinux` and the one with the problem is hosted on shared hosting.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'd expect this is a local browser setting, not something you can control in WP.

Comment: I dont think so... why one website does that and other doesnt ? If it was browser related surely one of the others (opera, chrome, ie) would open it but they all do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<FilesMatch "\.(docx|DOCX)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Huge thanks! It works. Tho its weird why would it do that ?

Comment: Not the answering party but it works because you force the document to be provided as a stream. Normally, when this is not done, it's up to the client's browser to interpret this. The fallback option for files which can not be handled in most cases is to just download them. If the browser itself is left to decide the outcome, it might open on one client's pc and download on the other. This effectively somewhat bypasses the browser's option to check if it can be opened in something like MS Office 365.